# Customizing navigation bar in beamer

Tags: beamer, xetex, presentations

I would like to customize the navigation bar (I'm using smoothbars) in beamer but I do not know how to proceed. To be more precise, I would like that all sections that appear on the navigation bar to be highlighted at the titlepage slide.

This is the current situation, all of the topics shown on the navigation bar are not highlighted at the titlepage slide.
[image]

I would like that all of the topics shown on the navigation to be highlighted at the titlepage slide. The image below shows the highlight of the section CV when a frame is in this section.
[image]

Here follows an MWE of the present situation:

```
 \documentclass[xetex]{beamer}

% To make the navigation bullets appear
\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter
    \@removefromreset{subsection}{section}
\makeatother
\setcounter{subsection}{1}

     \mode<presentation>
    {
      \useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}
      \setbeamercovered{transparent}
      \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} %remove navigation symbols
      \setbeamercovered{invisible} %No transparent layers
    }

    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{french}

    \setbeamerfont{headline}{series=\bfseries}

    \title{Audition}
    \author[John Doe]{\bfseries John Doe}
    \institute{Université}
    \date[19/05/15]{\today}


    \begin{document}
    \frame{ % This is the title slide where I'd like to highlight the sections
            \frametitle{}
            \setbeamertemplate{footline}{} 
            \maketitle  
    }

    \section{CV}
    \frame{}\frame{}\frame{}

    \section{Activités d'enseignement}
    \frame{}\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}

    \section{Activités de recherche}
    \frame{}\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}

    \section{Intégration}
    \frame{}\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}

    \section{Conclusion}
    \frame{}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: For a MWE you could start with a basic document, include a theme which is using miniframes and some sections and frames to reproduce your situation. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the current section is not highlighted, but the other ones are shaded. So if you temporally revoke the shading by setting its value to `100`, you get all sections "highlighted".

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} %remove navigation symbols
\setbeamercovered{invisible} %No transparent layers

\setbeamerfont{headline}{series=\bfseries}

\title{Audition}
\author[John Doe]{\bfseries John Doe}
\institute{Université}
\date[19/05/15]{\today}

\begin{document}
{   
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}[default][100]
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}[default][100]
\frame{ % This is the title slide where I'd like to highlight the sections
  \frametitle{}
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}{} 
  \maketitle  
}
}

\section{CV}
\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}

\section{Activités d'enseignement}
\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}

\section{Activités de recherche}
\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}

\section{Intégration}
\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}

\section{Conclusion}
\frame{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

In order to get filled circles on the titlepage, try this

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} %remove navigation symbols
\setbeamercovered{invisible} %No transparent layers

\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{subsection}{section}
\makeatother
\setcounter{subsection}{1}

\setbeamerfont{headline}{series=\bfseries}

\title{Audition}
\author[John Doe]{\bfseries John Doe}
\institute{Université}
\date[19/05/15]{\today}

\begin{document}
{
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}[default][100]
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}{%
    \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{0.1cm}{0.1cm}%
        \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0.05cm}{0.05cm}}{0.05cm}%
        \pgfusepath{fill,stroke}%
    \end{pgfpicture}%
}%
\frame{ % This is the title slide where I'd like to highlight the sections
  \frametitle{}
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}{} 
  \maketitle  
}
}

\section{CV}
\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}

\section{Activités d'enseignement}
\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}

\section{Activités de recherche}
\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}

\section{Intégration}
\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}

\section{Conclusion}
\frame{}
\end{document}
```

[image]